# Show only specific value in Textbox ax 2012

Tags: lookup, dynamics-ax-2012

I want to show only single value in lookup. 
Here is the image.

[image]

Right now this lookup is showing multiple values but I just want single value.

This is what I have have tried so far.

```
public void filter(str _filterStr)
{
   // super(_filterStr);
    container siteid= conNull();
    InventDim asb;

    while select *from asb where asb.InventSiteId==curUserId()
    {
        siteid+=asb.InventSiteId;
    }
    if (conLen(siteid)==4)
    {
        siteid=["No Site"];
    }
}
```

which method should I modify ?

[image]

Comment: Method `lookup`

Comment: I took a closer look at this on my AX 2012 R3 CU11 machine. It seems that this specific control is a bit of a special case that enables the lookup by the properties `FilterDataSource` and `FilterField`. Also I was not able to overwrite any of the form control methods like it is shown in your screenshot. Could you [edit] into your question what version of AX 2012 you are using?

Comment: You can't add methods on this form because it is a list page. You will need to modify methods in the list page interaction class associated with this form.